# Emacs 23.1.1 with gdb - forcing source windows

Tags: emacs, gdb

I'm using emacs 23.1.1 with gdb and gdb-many-windows.

My question is if it's possible to force gdb to always use the main source window for stepping through the code.
What happens is that as I move through stack frames, if I happen to have the source file up in another emacs frames, emacs brings that frame to the foreground while leaving the *gud* frame in the background with keyboard focus.

What I'd like to do is to force emacs/gdb to use the primary source window for all tracing even if there is another frame with the same source file laying around somewhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: on debian with emacs 24.4.1, this still happens to me. FWIW, i found a bug report, but without (yet) any patch: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2014-06/msg00097.html

Answer (score 4):

My emacs version is 24.3. So I am not really sure whether the following advice will solve your problem:

```lisp
(defadvice gud-display-line (before one-source-window activate)
  "Always use the same window to show source code."
  (let ((buf (get-file-buffer true-file)))
    (when (and buf gdb-source-window)
      (set-window-buffer gdb-source-window buf))))
```

I found `gud-display-line` with the arg `true-file` in the old source there:
http://www.mit.edu/~mkgray/stuff/ath/afs/oldfiles/project/silk/root/afs/athena.mit.edu/contrib/xemacs/OldFiles/share/xemacs-packages/lisp/debug/gdb.el

Furthermore, `gdb-source-window` can be found in a discussion about 23.1:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.emacs.bug/KS6bhNeJ9rc

Therefore, it looks like the things I used should be available in 23.1.

To avoid splitting of the window you can try this one:

```lisp
(defadvice gud-display-line (around one-source-window activate)
  "Always use the same window to show source code."
  (let ((buf (get-file-buffer true-file)))
    (when (and buf gdb-source-window)
      (set-window-buffer gdb-source-window buf)))
  (let (split-width-threshold split-width-threshold)
    ad-do-it
    ))
```

Comment: It works only on the first new one, if GDB open an other source file it splits the main window.

Comment: Let's see whether gud splits sensibly. Could you try to set `split-height-threshold` and `split-width-threshold` to `nil`?

Comment: @MarioGiovinazzo I have added a variant where I set `split-width-threshold` and `split-width-threshold` temporarily to nil to prevent the splitting of the main window. Please try.

Comment: I found that the defadvice might fix some annoyances with gdb-many-windows and gud loading source files into gdb windows (like comint buffer instead of the mid-left source window).  However, it doesn't seem to be reliable, I can still trigger this problem.  I suspect its the same bug as here with frames.  I wrote down my observations here http://nurpax.github.io/posts/2014-10-12-fixing-gdb-many-windows-source-buffer.html.

Comment: @Nurpax See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226626/emacs-gdb-always-display-source-in-specific-window-with-gdb-many-windows

Answer (score 1):

Update for more recent versions of emacs based on Tobias' advice (tested on emacs 27):

```lisp
  (defun my-set-source-window (wrapped true-file line)
   "Always use the same window to show source code."
   (let ((buf (get-file-buffer true-file)))
     (when (and buf gdb-source-window)
      (set-window-buffer gdb-source-window buf)))
   (let (split-width-threshold split-width-threshold)
    (apply wrapped (list true-file line))))

  (advice-add 'gud-display-line :around #'my-set-source-window)
```